# How to gather more views for a posted question other than putting bounties?

Tags: support, meta, views

I am new to Stack Exchange and want to know how shall I increase the view of my question which is not getting answered and has gathered small no. of views.

I have used `bounties` in stack overflow in past in order to increase the view count and successfully get the required answer but what if I'm new to some other website of `Stack Exchange` and do not have enough reputation to put bounties?

I know that **editing** can help and have done it but still, the question remains less viewed.

One of my question on [datascience.stackexchange](http://datascience.stackexchange.com) has gathered fewer views and I'm new to that site. I can't offer bounties on it, so Is there any way to tackle with this?

EDIT: If the question has answers and none of them are helpful then at least there is a chance that people who answered may soon find the right/helpful or at least look into the depth of question. But, here I'm asking about a scenario where the question hasn't received any answers and fewer views.

Comment: @Jenayah I hope the edit makes it different but not the answers !!

Comment: Not sure what you mean? "Without a good answer" doesn't necessarily mean there are unhelpful answers? It also applies when there's 0 answers, I think.

Comment: Well, the other question gives rise to some possibility of the required answer to be delivered in the future but 0 answer doesn't do so !!

Comment: Still not sure what you mean, sorry :/ if you're lacking a helpful answer (no matter whether you already have other answers or not), then surely the guidelines in the duplicate should prove helpful? If you don't feel like they do - why?

Comment: I'd be easier to help you seeing the actual question that got too few views. I suggest asking on Stack Overflow Meta for how you can improve a specific question.

Answer (score 2):

There are some things that make good questions, and there are other things that create many views.

Views are attracted by questions containing popular buzzwords and that are easy intelligible to lay people. Such questions are often shallow, but nevertheless they get a lot of attention. Shallow questions are often easy to answer and the answers gets a lot of votes.

Good questions are well formulated and contain thought. Good questions are often not-so-easy to answer and the answers usually get only a handful of votes. Choosing good tags and exhausting the limit of five tags helps a good question to be seen.

It is a principal dilemma that cannot really be solved.

P.S. Ah, please note that when you are coming from stack overflow all other site are low-traffic sites. In fact, most of them are very-low-traffic sites. Be patient!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have enough reputation to start bounties, there are two good things you can do:

1. Edit your question to make it really good
2. Earn enough reputation to start bounties

Admittedly, there's no perfect replacement for bounties, so the second option is most likely going to yield the best results.

Comment: I've tried your first solution and for the second one, I think it is not always   necessary to have a new question in mind related to the specific site or specific topic and then wait for the answer of the first question to get answered till the reputation on the particular site goes up.

Comment: @AjaySinghNegi it doesn't really matter how you get the 75 reputation. If you want to do it another way, it would work just as well.

Comment: As compared to a regular user, a newbie can't easily gain that much reputation within a short period of time.

Comment: @AjaySinghNegi then you can just stick with editing until you get enough reputation. Also remember that if you get 200 reputation on just one site, you will earn 100 reputation on every site.

Comment: Aah, that's something helpful. Looks as if I need to wait !!